# Create ArrayList of custom object pairs from two ArrayLists

Tags: java

Suppose I have two `ArrayList`: `{10}` and `{0, 1, 2}`

I need to make a third `ArrayList` that contains combinations of all these. The combinations can be held in a custom object, but it should basically come out to this:
`{(10, 0), (10, 1), (10, 2)}`

I would need it to work similarly for two `ArrayList` of variable sizes.

I'm trying something like this, but it seems to have issues with out of bound exceptions for various arrays.

```
for (int i : array1)
{
    for (int j : array2)
    {
        pairsArray.add(new Pair(array1.get(i), array2.get(j)));
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct except the line with object creation. As you're using a foreach loop you shouldn't invoke `get`, your `i` and `j` already contains the objects you need (in this case not actually objects but primitive ints). So your loop should look like this:

```
for (int i : array1) {
    for (int j : array2) {
        pairsArray.add(new Pair(i, j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
List lOne, lTwo, lThree;
for(obj obj1 : lOne){
   for(obj obj2 : lTwo){
       lThree.add(obj1, obj2);
   }
}
```

if you want to calculate the size it would be:
`numOfElements = sizeLOne * sizeLTwo`

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < len(lOne); i++){
    obj1 = lOne.get(i); 
    for(int j = 0 ; j len(lTwo); j++){
        lThree.add(obj1, lTwo.get(j));
    }
}
```